# I just removed a folder in /tmp/ and now apache/mysql is bugged. What just happened?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

So I just deleted a folder and a file in /tmp/ on my ubuntu server (12.10). Now everything related to MySQL is bugged. It also seems like the root mysql account I created has reset. When trying to log in using PHPMyadmin:

> Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

And when typing in "MySQL" using SSH (putty)

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

What just happened and How do I fix it?

Also, I just checked the status and it's offline. Will not start back up. `Job failed.`

Just restarted the server as well as mysql.

```
stop: Unknown instance: start: Job failed to start


130219 22:17:42 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
130219 22:18:01 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
130219 22:18:01 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130219 22:18:01 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130219 22:18:01 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130219 22:18:01 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
130219 22:18:01 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
130219 22:18:01 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130219 22:18:01 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130219 22:18:01 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130219 22:18:01 InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130219 22:18:02 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 69234959 /usr/sbin/mysqld: Too many arguments (first extra is 'restart'). Use --verbose --help to get a list of available options
130219 22:18:02 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I am using Ubuntu Server.

When trying to restart mysql using `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

```
Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the stop(8) and then start(8) utilities,
e.g. stop mysql ; start mysql. The restart(8) utility is also available.
start: Job failed to start
```

MySQL error log:

```
130220  8:15:54 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130220  8:15:54 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130220  8:15:54 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130220  8:15:54 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
130220  8:15:54 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
130220  8:15:54 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130220  8:15:54 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130220  8:15:54 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130220  8:15:54  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130220  8:15:55 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 69234959
130220  8:15:55 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3305
130220  8:15:55 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
130220  8:15:55 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
130220  8:15:55 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130220  8:15:55 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.10.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3305  (Ubuntu)
130220  8:16:16 [ERROR] mysqld: Table './site_forum/mybb_datacache' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
130220  8:16:16 [Warning] Checking table:   './site_forum/mybb_datacache'
130220  8:16:16 [ERROR] mysqld: Table './site_forum/mybb_themes' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
130220  8:16:16 [Warning] Checking table:   './site_forum/mybb_themes'
130220  8:16:16 [ERROR] mysqld: Table './site_forum/mybb_templates' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
130220  8:16:16 [Warning] Checking table:   './site_forum/mybb_templates'
130220  8:16:16 [ERROR] mysqld: Table './site_forum/mybb_forums' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
130220  8:16:16 [Warning] Checking table:   './site_forum/mybb_forums'
130220  8:16:16 [ERROR] mysqld: Table './site_forum/mybb_threads' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
130220  8:16:16 [Warning] Checking table:   './site_forum/mybb_threads'
130220  8:16:16 [ERROR] mysqld: Table './site_forum/mybb_posts' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
130220  8:16:16 [Warning] Checking table:   './site_forum/mybb_posts'
130220  8:16:16 [ERROR] Got an error from unknown thread, /build/buildd/mysql-5.5-5.5.29/storage/myisam/ha_myisam.cc:912
130220  8:16:16 [Warning] Recovering table: './site_forum/mybb_posts'
130220  8:16:16 [Note] Retrying repair of: './site_forum/mybb_posts' with keycache
130220  8:16:16 [ERROR] mysqld: Disk is full writing './site_forum/mybb_posts.TMD' (Errcode: 28). Waiting for someone to free space... (Expect up to 60 secs delay for server to continue after freeing disk space)
130220  8:16:16 [ERROR] mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs
130220  8:16:51 [ERROR] mysqld: Table './site_forum/mybb_spiders' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
130220  8:16:51 [Warning] Checking table:   './site_forum/mybb_spiders'
130220  8:16:51 [ERROR] mysqld: Table './site_forum/mybb_sessions' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
130220  8:16:51 [Warning] Checking table:   './site_forum/mybb_sessions'
130220  8:18:40 [ERROR] mysqld: Table './site_forum/mybb_users' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
130220  8:18:40 [Warning] Checking table:   './site_forum/mybb_users'
130220  8:18:40 [ERROR] mysqld: Table './site_forum/mybb_userfields' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
130220  8:18:40 [Warning] Checking table:   './site_forum/mybb_userfields'
130220  8:18:40 [ERROR] mysqld: Table './site_forum/mybb_privatemessages' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
130220  8:18:40 [Warning] Checking table:   './site_forum/mybb_privatemessages'

Status information:

Current dir: /var/lib/mysql/
Running threads: 21  Stack size: 196608
Current locks:
lock: 0x7f50c80229c0:

lock: 0x7f50c801fd20:

lock: 0x7f50c80183a0:

lock: 0x7f50e0009c10:

lock: 0x7f50e4010160:

lock: 0x7f50e400b490:

lock: 0x7f50f0028930:

lock: 0x7f50f00235e0:

lock: 0x7f50f0037320:

lock: 0x7f50f001dcc0:

lock: 0x7f50f0002de0:

lock: 0x7f50f0015270:

lock: 0x7f50ec0866b0:

lock: 0x7f50ec02d690:

lock: 0x7f50ec02bb90:

lock: 0x7f50ec0105a0:
```

df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs           20G   19G     0 100% /
/dev/root        20G   19G     0 100% /
none            3.2G  280K  3.2G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             16G     0   16G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
overflow        1.0M  8.0K 1016K   1% /tmp
/dev/md3         92G   20G   68G  23% /home
```

Comment: So what *was* the file you deleted?

Comment: If it really was just a file in the /tmp folder, as long as these services were following the Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard, simply restarting these services should resolve any issues...

Comment: I can't remember. It was a folder and perhaps mysql-socket, or something.

Comment: Restarted server as well as the services. I get job failed to start.

Comment: Why did you just blindly remove a file without thinking what it does? Check your shell history (probably `~/.bash_history`

Comment: I press "delete" on my keyboard when I was in sftp. :(

Comment: @deed02392 Nothing related to deleting the files in ~/.bash_history.

Comment: What does `sudo service mysql start` say? If it fails, please show us the error log `/var/log/mysql/error.log`.

Comment: @quanta Okay, done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the error log itself:

> 130220  8:16:16 [ERROR] mysqld: Disk is full writing
>   './site_forum/mybb_posts.TMD' (Errcode: 28). Waiting for someone to
>   free space... (Expect up to 60 secs delay for server to continue after
>   freeing disk space)

```
$ perror 28
OS error code  28:  No space left on device
```

I would suggest you to install [ncdu](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu), then run `ncdu /` to find large files/folders and delete them.

---

**df -h**

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs           20G   19G     0 100% /
/dev/root        20G   19G     0 100% /
none            3.2G  280K  3.2G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             16G     0   16G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
overflow        1.0M  8.0K 1016K   1% /tmp
/dev/md3         92G   20G   68G  23% /home
```

OK. Move the datadir to `/home` by running:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/mysql /home
```

Don't forget to change the owner of the new folder:

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /home/mysql
```

then create a symbolic link in order not to have to change the `datadir` in `my.cnf`:

```
sudo ln -s /home/mysql/ /var/lib/mysql
```

Now try to start the MySQL to see it works.

Comment: Alright, I think I know what's wrong now. OVH, my provider has by default limit some directories and give the rest to /home. So i guess I need to re-install the OS and give the root directory full space. Am I correct? If so, do you know the best way to backup files, including SQL?

Comment: OVH puts the `/` on a different partition to `/home`. You could just move the database files to a new dir on that partition, e.g. `/home/mysql`. You aren't going to be able to repartition it very easily without KVM.

Comment: There is a partition manager when re-installing. So in your opnion, do you think its best to just move mysql or re-install?

Comment: No need to re-install. Post the output of `df -h`.

Comment: Okay, edited, and done.

Comment: @devs: updated my answer.

Comment: Well, it's running! I get some SQL errors though. 144 - Table './site_forum/mybb_posts' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed

Comment: @devs: what are those errors? Crashed tables?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7593/discussion-between-devs-and-quanta)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you deleted any SQL files, they shouldn't be in `/tmp`

I assume you deleted the socket file which was used to communicate with the MySQL server.

Try to restart mysql and see if it recreates it, including the folder.

Otherwise try to recreate the folder manually and put open permissions on it, like `chmod 777 <folder>` and restart MySQL again.

Comment: I created a mysql-sock file, but can not remember the folder name.

Comment: you shouldn't create a file with the name of the socket manually, otherwise MySQL can't overwrite it with a socket file. Did you try just restarting MySQL?

Comment: I edited my answer to the message I get when trying to restart MySQL

Comment: Would re-install mysql-server remove any SQL?

Comment: `sudo mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld/ && sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld`